# pip: current (Python 3.6+) equivalent of `npm -g install some-global-package`?

Tags: macos, pip, python-3.6

**env: Python 3.6, on macos Mojave.  system python is 2.7, Apple's, which we can totally ignore**

(I'm not sure how much macos matters here)

How do I install something that has nothing to do with any given project but which I just want at the workstation/user level.  For example, `black`.  Either for my user, or, with `sudo` at the system level for Python 3.6.

So: **not in a virtualenv**.

### Here's a little tour of what I looked for/tried:

#### pip's help:

looking for `global` in `pip install -h | less` shows nothing very promising.

#### let's try the `--user` switch within a venv

```
(venv)$pip install black --user
ERROR: Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.
```

#### deactivate the virtualenv, run against `-m pip`

```
$ python3.6 -m pip install black
/opt/local/bin/python3.6: No module named pip
```

#### can I find pip binaries to work with?

```
$which python3.6
/opt/local/bin/python3.6   #  macports'
```

don't see any system pips:

```
$ mdfind -name pip | egrep /bin/ | egrep -v $USER
$ which pip3.6
$ which pip3
$ which pip
which pip36
```

macports search doesn't show any pip3s to install:

```
port search pip | egrep ^pip
pip_select @0.1_1 (python)
pipebench @0.40 (benchmarks, sysutils)
pipenv @2018.11.26 (python, devel)
pipsi @20180610_1 (python, sysutils)
pip script installer
pipx @0.15.1.3 (python, sysutils)
pipe to browser utility
```

#### But it can be done - here's what's in my global `site-packages`:

For example, the `meld` stuff comes from an unsuccessful install of meld, with sudo, of course.

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
$ ls
total 40
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   806 Oct  5  2018 pygobject-3.28.3-py3.6.egg-info
...
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   798 Feb 28 10:58 meld-3.18.1-py3.6.egg-info  
drwxr-xr-x   34 root  wheel  1088 Feb 28 10:58 meld
```

Comment: `pip install --user pkgname` is the correct command (or bootstrapped `python -m pip` as an alternative). The real issue here is that you are missing `pip`, but that's a different story. Looks like python package that macports offers is borked or incomplete - don't use that. Uninstall that, then use one of the official installers from https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/.

Comment: @hoefling I get substantially the same behavior from python 3.6.9 through apt-get on Ubuntu LTS 18.04, so not sure about your point.

Comment: On Ubuntu, `pip` is not included in the distribution by distro maintainers and has to be installed separately. `apt install python3-pip`.

Comment: [Macports also lists the `py36-pip` as a separate package](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=library&substr=py36-pip), so it should be installed separately. My point is pretty clear - either use the official installers, install once, get the complete distribution installed, no fuzz, or assemble the distribution from possibly multiple packages using the package manager of your choice (`brew`, `macports` etc).

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.

#### Determine the python3 you want to use.

I know I am mostly on 3.6, so...

`which python3.6`

output:

`/opt/local/bin/python3.6`

#### Follow [pypa's instructions](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) to install pip on its own

download install script

`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`

run it

`python3.6 get-pip.py`

There's a bit of verbiage stating that it could not write to `site-packages` in the system directories so it wrote them in user mode.

In my case, this means `~/Library/Python/3.6`

`tree -d -L 3 ~/Library/Python/3.6/`

```
~/Library/Python/3.6/
├── bin
└── lib
    └── python
        └── site-packages
```

#### add the bin to the $PATH

It also tells gives you all sorts of warning about `~/Library/Python/3.6/bin` not being on the path.  So add it.

`export PATH="$PATH:~/Library/Python/3.6/bin"`

You now have a working pip that points to your python3.6, without a virtualenv.

#### Alternatively, rather than fussing with the path:

Once you have installed pip globally, for that version of Python, you can specify the Python executable and call its pip:

`python3.6 -m pip install pre_commit black`

`which pip`

`~/Library/Python/3.6/bin/pip`

Speaking of **pip**, guess how pip knows which Python it is linked to?

`head -2 $(which pip)`

#### output:  notice the bash shebang

```
#!/opt/local/bin/python3.6
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

### usage

Deactivate your venv if you are in one

`deactivate`

Pip install

```
pip install pre_commit
pip install black
```

You may need to enable the global packages, with `--system-site-packages`, when creating a new virtualenv

`python3.6 -m venv venv --system-site-packages`

#### Reasons for doing this?

Well, for example, **black** has a pre-commit hook that relies on a Python package (**pre-commit**) to work.  Great stuff, but do you really need those 2 packages in each and every single virtualenv you build and do you need them as dependencies from `pip freeze`?